# imap gmail fetch message macosx

Tags: php, imap, gmail-imap

planning to use php imap functions, I'm trying to test the imap protocol from my local host,
I didn't found telnet-ssl for mac but I can use openssl and
get connected.

The problem is I can only login but I cannot select a mailbox,
create a mailbox, get a list, …
The only command I can run is capability which is not really useful.

Here is the command I typed (#) and answers I get (*)

```
# openssl s_client -connect imap.gmail.com:993

* CONNECTED(00000003)
* […]
* OK Gimap ready for requests from 77.xxx.xxx.xxx v7if3901328vdd.33

# a001 login myUserName myPassword

* OK myUserName firstname lastname authenticated (Success)



# a002 create testbox

* (nothing, I have to start a new session)

OR

# a002 list "*"
* (nothing, I have to start a new session)

OR

…
```

Not sure where the problem is,

Was someone able to fetch some mails successfully
from gmail (or other) using imap on mac ?
(I'm on osX10.6)

Comment: fetchmail is good for this...

Answer (score 2):

I think this may be a line-ending issue.  [Use the `-crlf` switch and it *should* work](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/s_client.html):

```
-crlf

    this option translated a line feed from the terminal into CR+LF as required
    by some servers.
```

[This is the command I've always used to test Gmail IMAP](http://qmail.jms1.net/test-auth.shtml), and it's worked fine for me from a Mac:

```
openssl s_client -crlf -connect imap.gmail.com:993
```

Also, your `LIST` command has bad syntax.  You need two parameters, not one:

```
a002 list "" "*"
```

Comment: Yes, that did it ! thank you very much, just feel ashamed that this was just on the man page(as it always is) and I don't know why I overlooked it.

Comment: @ling: If this answered your question, please [click on the checkmark outline](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) to the left of the answer.  It makes the solution clear to the next person with the same issue...

Answer (score 1):

Use `fetchmail` and `procmail` to build a local mailbox. Create `~/.fetchmailrc` containing...

```
set postmaster your_local_username
set syslog
set daemon 10
set logfile fetchmail.log

poll "imap.gmail.com" proto imap port 993
    user "gmailaddress@gmail.com" password "password"
    is your_local_username here keep ssl
```

Then setup `procmail` to store the messages...

In your `~` folder, create `.procmailrc` containing...

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
DEFAULT=$HOME/.mail/Maildir/ 
MAILDIR=$HOME/.mail/Maildir/
LOCKFILE=$HOME/.mail/.lock
LOGFILE=$HOME/.procmail/log
```

You may need to make these folders too, I forget.

To begin fetch mail with procmail do:

```
fetchmail -kFm "/usr/bin/procmail -d %T"
```

You can use something like `mutt` to read the mail, personally I don't read mail manually that I'm doing a fetchmail with, I would use it for email automation, which is what procmail is good at, essentially you can create 'recipes' to filter, process and redirect messages.

Wikipedia has a reasonable starting point for [learning more about procmail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procmail). The `man fetchmail` and `man procmail` pages also have a lot of useful info.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out other solutions,
I  planned to use php imap functions to fetch messages
since there are php imap functions and tutorials.
Now I didn't know about fetchmail and I don't find fetchmail functions
for php, but now I know it's possible ;)
Still I would like to solve my "imap gmail configuration" problem first.

Comment: Oh, that's ok, I've added PHP to your tags. But your question really mentions nothing at all about PHP, just about how to do this on Mac Os X. So you may want to reword your question to get the answers you want. BTW there are plenty of resources for fetchmail and gmail.